# Is there a way to reduce the binary size of a Cobra app

Tags: go, go-cobra

I'd like to use [Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) in a project where I have some strict binary size limitations. The binary size of a "hello world" Cobra app (as shown below) comes in at 4.1 MB. If I build it with `go build -ldflags "-w -s" .` then I can get it down to 2.8 MB. Does Cobra have any build tags (or other methods) to give up any functionality to further reduce the binary size? As an example, the Gin library has a [-tags=nomsgpack](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#build-without-msgpack-rendering-feature) flag to disable the `MsgPack` rendering feature. Does Cobra offer anything like that?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {
    if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "hugo",
    Short: "Hugo is a very fast static site generator",
    Long: `A Fast and Flexible Static Site Generator built with
                love by spf13 and friends in Go.
                Complete documentation is available at https://gohugo.io/documentation/`,
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {

    },
}
```

Comment: If the target OS is Linux, consider trying [UPX](https://upx.github.io/). Be mindful that, because a Go binary embarks the Go runtime, its size cannot be reduced much below 500kb, which is the typical size of a Linux binary of a Hello World program, built with `go build -ldflags "-w -s" .` and to which UPX has been applied.

Comment: There are no build constraints other than `windows` in cobra, so there is nothing to conditionally compile.

Comment: Opinion-y comment here: but why the need for `Cobra`? I've developed many command-line tools in `go` over the years - and never had the need for any third-party command-line arg parsing libraries. The standard library `flags` package works just fine.

Comment: @colm.anseo, you are correct that in my case Cobra is a a nice-to-have and not a need. The `flag` package, as the name implies, does flags only (options) and not commands/sub-commands. The `flag` package also does not support POSIX compliant flags, hence the existence of [pflag](https://github.com/spf13/pflag) that is used by Cobra.

Comment: @SamHerrmann you are correct, the `flag` does not support `POSIX` flags - you can however support sub-commands by leveraging multiple [flag.FlagSet](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#FlagSet)'s

Comment: No one really wants POSIX flags which only support single letter options, `pflag` supports gnu style flags. FWIW in my experience the go flags have only simplified CLI usage once users realize there is nothing special about `--long` options and don't need ambiguous interleaved flags and positional arguments.

Comment: @colm.anseo I can second that "opinion-y comment". No need to bring out the big guns. Minimalism should prevail.